# Как сделать так чтоб было доходил до другого блока

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так чтобы блок block2 со значение width 100vh доходил до блока block3 а не игнорировал его?

```css
html {
    background: black;
}

.block1 {
    background: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}

.block2 {
    background: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}

.block3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: green;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
}

.block2_block {
    margin: 7px 50px;
    background: yellow;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>BIRDFARM</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
  <style>
input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:#fff;}
::-moz-placeholder          {color:#fff;}/* Firefox 19+ */
:-moz-placeholder           {color:#fff;}/* Firefox 18- */
:-ms-input-placeholder      {color:#fff;}
</style>
<body>
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2">
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="block3"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что значит "игнорировал"? у вас блок3 абсолютный! Может в этом проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Если под "доходил до" подразумевается был между блок1 и блок2, и под "не игнорировал" подразумевается, что блок3 (зеленый) вылезает куда-то не туда, то уберите

```
.block3{
    position:absolute; /* убрать */
}
```